# Export table from Access to Oracle converts number to Varchar how to make it stop doing that?

Tags: oracle, ms-access, export

I have a table in Access 2007 with various number columns, but when i export the table from Access all the number fields are converted to varchar2. I am using an Access odbc for oracle

Comment: What makes you think it's converted to varchar2?

Comment: What are you using to export it? Some utility or Access's Export menu option through an ODBC connection?

Answer (score 0):

Use Number for Data Type and for field size use decimal